# Using Iwona as a math font with lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex

I would like to use Iwona as a math font, but this setup doesn't get all math symbols right. (Multiline bracket, the sum symbol, etc.)

```
\setmathfont{Iwona}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]  {Iwona}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Iwona Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Iwona Bold Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]  {Iwona Italic}
```

I guess that Iwona doesn't have all the math symbols that are necessary, so what should I do?

(But at this link, http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/iwona/, I notice that the math symbols are available). I am a bit puzzled.

Edit my preamble

```
documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,oneside,openany,titlepage,frontespizio,headinclude,,footinclude,BCOR5mm,cleardoublepage=empty,tablecaptionabove,]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\PassOptionsToPackage{protrusion=true,final}{microtype}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,pdfspacing,listings]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\setmainfont[Microtype,Ligatures=TeX]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Iwona}
\setmathfont{Iwona} %
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]  {Iwona}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Iwona Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Iwona Bold Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]  {Iwona Italic}
```

Comment: May be `\usepackage[math]{iwona}\usepackage[no-maths]{fontspec}…`?

Comment: It *might* be helpful to see your preamble as well.

Comment: @Manuel it doesn't solve the problem, and I get an additional warning, `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/iwona/m/n' undefined`.

Comment: Iwona has no OpenType math font, so using `unicode-math` is out of the question.

Comment: @thunder1123 You weren't telling us the whole story. What is `arsclassica` meant to? And `classicthesis`? Both of them change the math font. `unicode-math` has no place there as egreg said…

Comment: sorry, I forgot that they were changing the math..anyway, how should I overrride their behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find no reason whatsoever for having math in Iwona when the main text font is Minion Pro. However, here's how you can do it:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  openright,
  oneside,
  openany,
  titlepage,
  headinclude,
  footinclude,
  BCOR5mm,
  cleardoublepage=empty,
  tablecaptionabove,
]{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{protrusion=true,final}{microtype}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,pdfspacing,listings]{classicthesis}    
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\setmainfont[Microtype,Ligatures=TeX]{Minion Pro}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \SetSymbolFont{operators}{iwona}\g_fontspec_encoding_tl\g__fontspec_mathrm_tl\mddefault\updefault
  \SetSymbolFont{operators}{iwonabold}\g_fontspec_encoding_tl\g__fontspec_mathrm_tl\bfdefault\updefault
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{2\arcsin 1}=\sqrt[4]{6\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{k^{2}}}=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx \quad\text{text}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that there is no OpenType math font for Iwona, so using `unicode-math` is out of the question. The lines between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` are to use the text font for operators and digits, otherwise Iwona would be used.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Loading `iwona` *before* `fontspec` (with the `no-math` option). Removing anything related to `unicode-math`. And commenting the packages `arsclassica` and `classicthesis` (there should be an option not to override the font, but I don't know right know, read the documentation, may be loading them before all the font packages is enough?). And then it compiles with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,oneside,openany,titlepage,frontespizio,headinclude,,footinclude,BCOR5mm,cleardoublepage=empty,tablecaptionabove,]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\PassOptionsToPackage{protrusion=true,final}{microtype}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\usepackage{subfig}                   
%\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,pdfspacing,listings]{classicthesis}              

%\usepackage{arsclassica}                   
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Microtype,Ligatures=TeX]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Helvetica}
%\setmathfont{Iwona} %
%\setmathfont[range=\mathup]  {Iwona} 
%\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Iwona Bold}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Iwona Bold Italic}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathit]  {Iwona Italic}
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \[
        \int_a^b f(x) dx
    \]
\end{document}
```